# Pass variable to created hook Vue.js for Firestore reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

**My goal is to:**

Load one document and get the value for "account"

Then load a new document with "account" as one of the document names in firestore. I am using this.account for the path

```
<script>
// eslint-disable-next-line
import firestore from "firestore";
// eslint-disable-next-line
import NewEmployee from "@/components/updatePopups/NewEmployee";
import db from "@/components/fbInit";
import firebase from "firebase";

export default {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  components: { NewEmployee },
  data() {
    return {
      account: "",
      users: [],
      acc:[],
    };
  },

    computed: {
      computed() {

     const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
     const info = [];

      db
    .collection("userProfiles")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      const doc1content = doc.data();

      return doc1content.account;
      console.log(doc1content.account)
    });
   }
  },

  created() {

      const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      let account = computed();
      let empRef = db.collection('userProfiles').doc(this.account).collection('employees');


      let empCollection = empRef.get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        this.users = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());

      const data = {
          id: doc.id,
          Name: doc.data().Name,
          GroupHex: doc.data().GroupHex,
          DeviceType: doc.data().DeviceType,
          UserIDInt: doc.data().UserIDInt,
          SuperID: doc.data().SuperID,
          misc: doc.data().misc,
          Status: doc.data().Status,
        };         
          this.users.push(data)
        });
      })
  },  
};
</script>
```

I keep getting undefined errors or value can't be "" or """

account is undefined
ReferenceError: computed is not defined

The reason I am not doing this all in one created hook is because I would like to use the snapshot feature to reload the page when there is a change automatically and I had trouble doing that when it was nested inside another doc.get(). I would like to have the "account" variable loaded and stored when the page is loaded(or before).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do but to access the computed property that you've (somewhat confusingly) called `computed` you would write `this.computed` instead of `computed()`. That should fix the *'not defined'* error. The value of that property will be a promise, not clear whether that is your intent. I would also stress that `account` and `this.account` are different things within your `created` hook, so currently you are assigning a value to the local variable `account` but then never using it, while `this.account` just seems to be an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right, I am confused at how this works. All I want to do is get a variable and store it so I can access it later in created. Not sure the best way of doing this.

1: get variable from firestore.
2 : use that variable in created

Comment: I am still getting undefined

Comment: If you wan to chain two queries in the `created()` hook, you can just do so within `created()`. Or if you really want to separate the two you can use a method instead of a computed value.